# Can not submit the form if one of the upload buttons out of two is not having an attachment in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic asp.net c# application which has a form to submit some data to database, This form has two upload buttons to upload two files.

Now whenever i upload both of the files and submit the form, it works properly. And whenever i submit the form without uploading even a single file (without any file) it also works properly.

But the issue is that when i upload just one file via one of the upload buttons and i keep the other upload button blank (without any file or attachment) and then submit the form then it generates an error as [Object reference not set to an instance of an object].

I think the issue is with the logic of if() block in my controller, BTW i tried different logic but non of it work.

This is the model:

```
  public class Events
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string Finance_Approval { get; set; }


    public string file_one { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file1 { get; set; }

    public string file_two { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file2 { get; set; }


}
```

This is the controller:

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Request(Events e)
    {


        if ((e.file1!=null && e.file1.ContentLength>0) || (e.file2!=null && e.file2.ContentLength>0))
        {

            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.file1.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.file1.FileName);
            filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            e.file_one = "PM_Files/" + filename;
            filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PM_Files/"), filename);
            e.file1.SaveAs(filename);

            string Second_filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.file2.FileName);
            string Second_extension = Path.GetExtension(e.file2.FileName);
            Second_filename = Second_filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Second_extension;
            e.file_two = "PM_Files/" + Second_filename;
            Second_filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PM_Files/"), Second_filename);
            e.file2.SaveAs(Second_filename);

            _context.evt.Add(e);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Content("Added");
        }


        else
        {


            _context.evt.Add(e);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Content("Added");


        }

    }
```

And this is the razor view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Request", "Requester", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.title, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.amount)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select the file word or pdf etc</label>
    <input type="file" name="file1" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select the file word or pdf etc</label>
    <input type="file" name="file2" />
</div>
<br/>


<button class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>
}
```

Comment: Yes, it’s probably your if statement. Now it says “if either file is set, handle both of them.” You don’t check for nulls for them inside the if so it’s completely possible for one to be null. Add the checks inside.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen any solutions?

Comment: @JohnKamaal, answer added

Comment: @JohnKamaal, glad to hear that you have get rid from your problem :)

Comment: @ershoaib thank you so much, you always help a lot. I truly appreciate your kind contribution

Comment: @er-shoaib buddy you gotta check this, if free.. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802276/in-a-single-razor-view-how-can-i-retrieve-values-passed-from-different-methods/53802398#53802398

Comment: @JohnKamaal, currently m not available, I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: @er-shoaib ok buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether file1 or file2 is null or not and depends upon you can save those files.

Try to modify your code like

```
public ActionResult Request(Events e)
    {
        //Check whether "e" is null or not
        if (e != null)
        {
            //Check whether "file1" is null or not
            if (e.file1 != null && e.file1.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.file1.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.file1.FileName);
                filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                e.file_one = "PM_Files/" + filename;
                filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PM_Files/"), filename);
                e.file1.SaveAs(filename);
            }

            //Check whether "file2" is null or not
            if (e.file2 != null && e.file2.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string Second_filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.file2.FileName);
                string Second_extension = Path.GetExtension(e.file2.FileName);
                Second_filename = Second_filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Second_extension;
                e.file_two = "PM_Files/" + Second_filename;
                Second_filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PM_Files/"), Second_filename);
                e.file2.SaveAs(Second_filename);
            }

            _context.evt.Add(e);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Content("Added");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Event is empty");
        }

    }
```